# split tunnel vpn access point

Tags: iptables, vpn, openconnect

I have not been able to find out how to do this.

I have a vpn access point which uses openconnect and hostapd with the following vpn iptables rules

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/iptables.ipv4.vpn.nat
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Sep  4 02:28:21 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:152]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2:152] 
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlan1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Sep  4 02:28:21 2016 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Sep  4 02:28:21 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5:380]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Sep  4 02:28:21 2016
```

and the following non vpn'd access point

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Sep  4 02:28:21 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:152]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2:152]
-A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wlan1 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Sep  4 02:28:21 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Sep  4 02:28:21 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5:380] 
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan1 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Sep  4 02:28:21 2016
```

There are a few IP's that are not accessible from within the VPN so what I want to do is send all traffic through the vpn except for x.x.x.x and x.x.x.y for instance. For that traffic I just want it regularly nat'd so I can access it through the access point but not through the vpn.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking the problem.

Consider the two gateways for the two interfaces (the gateways, not the  IP addresses for the interfaces themselves)

```
gweth0=192.168.1.254
gwtun0=10.1.1.1
```

You can route these like this

```
route add default gw $gwtun0
route add -host x.x.x.x gw $gweth0
route add -host x.x.x.y gw $gweth0
```

You can even route entire subnets

```
route add -net a.b.c.d/24 gw $gweth0
```

The `iptables ... MASQUERADE` stuff is only required if you need to rewrite the IP addresses. From a single client that's unlikely.